# Appfabric Windows Workflow Service deployed on Amazon Web Services (AWS)

Tags: sql-server, amazon-ec2, workflow-foundation-4, appfabric

I have deployed Windows Workflow Service on Amazon Ec2 Instance (Virtual Machine). I also installed Appfabric Window Service on same Virtual Machine in order to monitor Workflow events.

I installed [Standalone AppFabric 1.1 version](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27115) so not choosing to install it  from Web Platform Installer as I did not wanted to  configure Sql Express on EC2 Instance (Virtual Machine). The install was successfull.

After the installation, I opened "Configure AppFabric" tool to set "Monitoring and Persistence Information" and am trying to update the settings to Connect To remote Amazon RDS Sql Database , it is also to inform that I did manually created AppFabric Monitoring and Persistence database in Amazon RDS Sql Server. But after specifying Remote Database details and using Sql Authentication when I try to click on Apply Button I get warning that "Sql Server Agent Job is not detected" and also when I invoke Window WorkFlow Service, the AppFabric Dashboard does not display any events.

Can any one help me to fix the problem or also whether AppFabric is compatible with Amazon Cloud EC2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was related to Sql Server Agent Job. Amazon RDS will not allow Sql Server Agent Job to be created as a part of Creation of AppFabric Montoring Database. But the Sql Server Agent Job can be manually created in Amazon RDS which will serve the purpose. The AppFabric Monitoring Database has 4 Sql Server Agent Jobs

The below jobs need to be manually Created in Amazon Rds
Microsoft_ApplicationServer_Monitoring_AutoPurge_AppFabricMonitoringStore
Microsoft_ApplicationServer_Monitoring_ImportTransferEvents_AppFabricMonitoringStore
Microsoft_ApplicationServer_Monitoring_ImportWcfEvents_AppFabricMonitoringStore
Microsoft_ApplicationServer_Monitoring_ImportWfEvents_AppFabricMonitoringStore